# Convert string to int if number

Tags: c++, if-statement, char, int

Below i have a code where i want to cin a certain values. In the event i cin a [ it should just ignore it. BUT in the event a user inserts a number and not a `[` it should convert the char into an int and insert it into `rows` in the else function. How can i convert this char into an int and place it into `rows`?

```
    char ignoreChar;

    is >> ignoreChar;

    if(ignoreChar == '[')
    {
    }

    else
    {
    rows = ignoreChar;
    }
```

Comment: What is `rows`? An `int`?

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to only use `cstdlib`? Because that looks like `<istream>` for me

Comment: pretend rows is already decalred before

Comment: If you are sure that `ignoreChar` is a digit, then `rows = ignoreChar - '0';` will work

Comment: @sonicboom: btw, I understood `rows` is declared before. I asked *what* is it declared like. An `int`?

Answer (score 1):

If you take proper care that the `ignoreChar` will contain a digit, you can easily convert it into an integer this way:

```
rows = ignoreChar - '0';
```

The `std::isdigit()` function can be used to check whether a certain character represents a digit.

You can take the following sample program as an inspiration:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = -1; // Equivalent of your "rows"

    char c; // Equivalent of your "ignoreChar"
    cin >> c;

    if (std::isdigit(c))
    {
        i = c - '0';
    }
    else
    {
        // Whatever...
    }

    cout << i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are entering only one character you should be able to type cast it.

int a = (int) whateverNameOfChar;

This will convert it to it's ASCII number though so you'll have to subtract '0'

Answer (score 0):

To convert a `char` that you know is one of `'0'` to `'9'` to an `int` of that numeric value, you can simply do:

```
rows = ignoreChar - '0';
```

This works because the numeric characters are guaranteed to have consecutive values by the standard.

If you need to determine whether the `char` is a digit or not, you can either use `std::isdigit(ignoreChar)` or a simple condition of `ignoreChar >= '0' && ignoreChar <= '9'`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different approaches to "reading user input".

Which one works best, depends a little on the format/style of input. You can consider two different formats, "Linebased" and "free form". Free form would be input like C source code where you can add newlines, spaces, etc wherever you like.

Linebased has a set format, where  each line contains a given set of inputs [not necessarily the same number of inputs, but the end of line terminates that particular input].

In a free-form input, you would have to read a character, then determine "what the meaning of this particular part is", and then decide what to do. Sometimes you also need to use the `peek()` function to check what the next character is, and then determine what to do based on that.

In a line-based input, you use `getline()` to read a line of text, and then split that into whatever format you need, for example using `stringstream`.

Next you have to decide whether you write your own code (or use some basic standard translation code) or use `stream` functions to parse for example numbers. Writing some more code will get you better ways to handle errors such as "1234aqj" isn't a number, but `stream` would simply stop reading when it reaches 'a' in that string.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the code that is much longer than might be. Below is an example code of "factorial counting" with entering symbols with their handling.  I tried to show different possibilities. The only problem I see now in it that there is no any reaction if a user just hit the Enter without any symbols entered. It is my the very first post here, so I'm very sorry with any possible fonts, formatting and other nonsense. 
MaxNum = 21 was empirically defined for the unsigned long long int return type.

I've checked such input cases: abcde 2. -7 22 21

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

unsigned long long int CalcFact( int p ) 
    { return p == 0 || p == 1 ? 1 : p*CalcFact(p-1); }

int main()
{
int MaxNum = 21, HowMany = 0, MaxAttempts = 5, Attempts = 0;
char AnyKey[] = "", *StrToOut = "The factorial of ", Num[3] = "";
bool IsOK = 0;

while( !IsOK && Attempts++ < MaxAttempts )
{
    std::cout << "Please enter an integer > 0 and <= 21: ";
    std::cin.width(sizeof(Num)/sizeof(char)); 
    std::cin >> Num;
    for( int Count = 0; Count < strlen(Num); Count++ )
        IsOK = isdigit(Num[Count]) ? true : false;
    if( IsOK )
    {
        if( !(atoi(Num) >= 0 && atoi(Num) <= MaxNum) )
            IsOK = false;
        else
        {
            for( int Count = 0; Count <= MaxNum; Count++ )
                {
                std::cout << StrToOut << Count << std::setfill('.') 
                << std::setw( Count < 10 ? 30 : 29 ) 
                << CalcFact(Count) << std::endl; 
                }
        }
    }
    if( !IsOK && Attempts > 0 )
    {
        std::cin.clear(); 
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
if( !IsOK ) 
    return -1;
else
    std::cin >> AnyKey;
return 0;
}
```